# Logical test in R - only three of four conditions have to be fulfilled

Tags: r

I have four conditions for a string, but only three of them have to be fulfilled.

Conditions:
 * At least one upper-case letter
 * At least one digit
 * At least one lower-case letter
 * At least one punctuation character

How can i write this as an if statement in R, which prints 'TRUE' if it is correct and 'FALSE' otherwise?

Comment: `Reduce("+",list(cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4))>=3`.

Comment: Or use `rowSums(cbind(cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4))>=3`

Answer (score 1):

#### example inputs

```
S1 <- "Aa1!"
S2 <- "eij20n."
S3 <- "ei20"
```

#### function

```
myfun <- function(S) {
                     # digit       # uppercase        # lowercase       #punctuation
             sum(grepl("\\d", S), grepl("[A-Z]",S), grepl("[a-z]",S), grepl("[.!?]",S)) >= 3 
         }

myfun(S1)
# TRUE
myfun(S2)
# TRUE
myfun(S3)
# FALSE
```

#### less verbose version of the function

```
myfun1 <- function(S) {
            pattern <- c("\\d", "[A-Z]", "[a-z]", "[.!?]")
            sum(sapply(pattern, function(x) grepl(x, S))) >= 3
          }
```